# Azure DevOps Build Dashboard Chart

Tags: charts, azure-devops, dashboard

What I seek : Create chart for number of builds initiated by each assigned user and factorize it based on success and failure, How can I proceed with this requirement ?

What I have done : I have created work item tracking charts from board queries.

What I have come across : A build widget which has history of success and build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Create chart for number of builds initiated by each assigned user and
>   factorize it based on success and failure

For this issue , I'm afraid that there is currently no out-of-the-box feature in Azure Devops to achieve this requirement.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

In addition , as a workaround ,you can try to use [Builds-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api to get a list of builds. Then through the script, you can retrieve the results according to the `result` and `requestedBy` parameters, and then count the number.

[image]
[image]